# FILTER and QUERY in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter

[image]

Hi everyone,

My goal is to calculate the number of students who choose Action 3 as one of their answer but the previous answer is not Action 2.

So based on the example in the screenshot above, `Mary`,`Lary` and `yuki` choose Action 3 as one of their answer, but only `Lary` having Action 2 as his previous answer. So the expected output in cell `B2` is `2` since the previous answer for `Mary` before Action 3 is Action 5 instead of Action 2 and for `yuki`, the previous answer before Action 3 is Action 1 instead of Action 2.

May I know how to automate this formula? I have no idea how to start to build this formula.

This is my google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zk7lr_2lEKEyY6qI0kNVXBHRF7mcsBJGDyR0BQjKyk0/edit#gid=0

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is this related to `jQuery`

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to count. By "students who choose Action 3 as one of their answer but the previous answer is not Action 2," do you mean A.) an action is Action 3 and the previous action is not Action 2 regardless of who the previous student is; or B.) an action is Action 3 and the previous action by the SAME STUDENT is not Action 2?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it should be an action is Action 3 and the previous action by the SAME STUDENT is not Action 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your replies to my questions in the comments section under the original post, I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet, with the following formula in B2 (currently highlighted in bright green):

`=ArrayFormula(SUM((C5:C="Action 3")*(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(A5:A)-1,{ROW(A5:A),C5:C},2,FALSE)<>"Action 2",0))*(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(A5:A)-1,{ROW(A5:A),B5:B},2,FALSE)=B5:B,0))))`

**ADDENDUM** (after reading additional comments):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help 2") with the following formula:

`=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B5:B,C5:C="Action 3",VLOOKUP(ROW(A5:A)-1,{ROW(A5:A),B5:B&C5:C},2,FALSE)<>B5:B&"Action 2")))`

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your solution! I tried it and it works well. However, in the case of having 2 `Action 3` within the same student and the previous action for both `Action 3` is not `Action 2`, then the formula actually counted it twice. Since it is the same student, by right the formula should only count once instead of twice if the event occur twice. I added in another two rows of data (row 25 & 26) under `Erik Help` to simulate the condition, hope there is a way to solve this problem, thank you!

Comment: See the ADDENDUM section in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=query({{offset(A4:C,1,0);"","",""},C4:C},"select count(Col1) where Col3 matches 'Action 3' and not Col4 matches 'Action 2' label count(Col1) '' ",1)`

[image]

For same student, try:

`=query({{query({A4:C},"where Col1 is not null order by Col2,Col1 offset 1",1);"","",""},query({A4:C},"where Col1 is not null order by Col2,Col1",1)},"select count(Col1) where Col2=Col5 and Col3 matches 'Action 3' and not Col6 matches 'Action 2' label count(Col1) '' ",1)`

To see the results, rather than counting them:

`=query({{query({A4:C},"where Col1 is not null order by Col2,Col1 offset 1",1);"","",""},query({A4:C},"where Col1 is not null order by Col2,Col1 label Col3 'Prev answer'",1)},"select * where Col2=Col5 and Col3 matches 'Action 3' and not Col6 matches 'Action 2' label count(Col1) '' ",1)`

Comment: Aresvik, I think there is currently an issue with your formula. Your OFFSET goes the wrong direction (i.e., it appears to me that the formula is comparing the current row of Col C against the FOLLOWING row in Col C rather than against the PREVIOUS row). In addition, it is unclear from the post where the count should account for sequence of actions by the SAME student or regardless of student. The first issue, you can adjust; the second requires more information from the poster, which I've requested via comment on the original post.

Comment: sorry for not making it clear enough, it should be the same student, seems like the current formula works regardless of student, is it possible to change so that the formula only check within the same student?

Comment: Formula added to answer.